# Pip is not installing on bash on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, python, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently updated my windows and install bash on ubuntu on windows 10.I use the command `sudo apt-get install python-pip`

[image: This is the snap of error im getting]

Comment: But did you try `sudo apt-get -f install`  **with no packages**? That's what the error message is asking you to do but there is no evidence you tried that.

Comment: Did you enable the "Universe" repository?

Comment: how to do that??

Comment: Do `sudo add-apt-repository universe`.

Comment: 'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

or

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

then

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

it will resolve your problem

Answer (score 24):

Simply run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

or `python-pip` depending on your version.

Apparently fresh install doesn't have full list of available packages cashed.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across this in the future, simply run:

```bsh
python3 -m pip install [package]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems Ubuntu on windows 10 is not up-to-date when install, run simply:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

if Python2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

if Python3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

To get pip for python3 (Python 2 is available by default for pip)

Comment: I just install Ubuntu, I run
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install python-pip
Then when I enter:
  python --version #error
  python3 --version #Python 3.6.7
  python2 --version #Python 2.7.15+

You are right! I add this to my answer. Thank you